# S3 Access Denied when copy object from one bucket to antother bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am working on a ruby on rails project running on AWS EB. Ruby version is 2.6. I want to use below code to copy file from source bucket to target bucket. But receive error: `Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied`.
AWS access keys are correct and I can put file to source bucket; also both source bucket and target bucket are in the same rigion. I cannot figure out why I get this error. Can you please help?

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

s3_src_key = terminal_id
s3_key = 'company/' + uuid

s3_src_obj = s3.bucket(ENV["AWS_PUBLIC_BUCKET"]).object(s3_src_key)
s3_obj = s3.bucket(ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]).object(s3_key)

s3_src_obj.copy_to(s3_obj)
```

Comment: I'd recommend looking at using an [Elasticbeanstalk Instance Profile][1] for resource permissions. For the actual question though, i'm not really sure. It could be a few things.

Troubleshooting - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

EB Instance profiles - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but troubleshooting steps:

1. Are the two buckets in the same AWS account? If not, please refer to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/
2. Does any of the two buckets has KMS encryption enabled? If yes, you will need to give the IAM user or Instance profile access to kms:Decrypt for read and kms:Encrypt for write. If any of the KMS keys is not owned by your AWS Account then please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html
3. Does any of the buckets have versioning enabled? If yes, please make sure to include s3:PutObjectVersion for writing and s3:GetObjectVersion for reading
4. Do you have bucket or object ACLs? If yes please make sure that they allow your read and write

If none of the above works for you, you may need to share some more information if possible as follows:

5. Do you have a Bucket policy? If so, please paste it here to check it further
6. Please paste the IAM user policy so we can trace it with you.